# Changing window size using PInvoke does not cause the client area to update

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to write a simple program that resizes an old game created in the 800x600 era of desktop monitors that doesn't have a resizable form border. So far I have been able to successfully change the window size using either `MoveWindow` or `SetWindowPos`, but the problem is the client area (i.e. the actual game) doesn't update; if the window size is increased the extra region is padded with black, and if it's decreased then the image is cropped. However, I have discovered that the show desktop button from Explorer will force the client area to update properly. Therefore, my question is how do I replicate what Explorer is doing when it shows the desktop, sans the minimizing everything part?

I have tried `RedrawWindow`, `UpdateWindow`, and even sending a `WM_PAINT` message directly but nothing seems to work. The game window also does not seem to have child windows, according to spy++.

**UPDATE**

I have just experimented with minimizing and then re-showing the window, and it does also fix the client area proper. This probably explains why show desktop worked before. Although this is a potential solution, ideally I'd like to be able to resize in-place rather than having to quickly minimize and then re-show.

**UPDATE2**

I've included the code used for testing below as requested, as well as a screenshot of the symptoms described above.

Test Code:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("magic string"))
{
    var h = process.MainWindowHandle;

    if (h == IntPtr.Zero)
        continue;

    GetWindowRect(h, out RECT rect);

    //define new window size
    int width = 646;
    int height = 509;

    MoveWindow(h, rect.Left, rect.Top, width, height, true);
    
    //working solution, but not visually ideal
    ShowWindow(h, ShowWindowCommands.Minimize);
    ShowWindow(h, ShowWindowCommands.Restore);

    //note: none of the below methods that attempt to force update work
    //(i.e. does not visibly scale the client area)

    //RedrawWindow attempts
    RedrawWindow(h, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, RedrawWindowFlags.EraseNow);
    RedrawWindow(h, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, RedrawWindowFlags.UpdateNow);
    RedrawWindow(h, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, RedrawWindowFlags.Invalidate);

    //SetWindowPos attempts
    SetWindowPos(h, IntPtr.Zero, rect.Left, rect.Top, width, height, SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    SetWindowPos(h, IntPtr.Zero, rect.Left, rect.Top, width, height, SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_DRAWFRAME);

    //send WM_PAINT
    SendMessage(h, WM_PAINT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

    //@dxiv's suggestion
    RedrawWindow(h, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, RedrawWindowFlags.Invalidate);
    RedrawWindow(h, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, RedrawWindowFlags.Erase);

    //@NetMage's suggestion
    UInt32 lParam = 0;
    lParam = (UInt32)((UInt16)height << 16 | (UInt16)width);
    SendMessage(h, WM_SIZE, IntPtr.Zero, new IntPtr(lParam));

    //@Drake Wu - MSFT's suggestion
    SetWindowPos(h, IntPtr.Zero, rect.Left, rect.Top, width, height, SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

PInvoke definitions:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int Width, int Height, bool Repaint);

private enum ShowWindowCommands : int
{
    Hide = 0,
    Normal = 1,
    ShowMinimized = 2,
    Maximize = 3, 
    ShowMaximized = 3,
    ShowNoActivate = 4,
    Show = 5,
    Minimize = 6,
    ShowMinNoActive = 7,
    ShowNA = 8,
    Restore = 9,
    ShowDefault = 10,
    ForceMinimize = 11
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, ShowWindowCommands nCmdShow);

[Flags]
private enum RedrawWindowFlags : uint
{
    Invalidate = 0x1,
    InternalPaint = 0x2,
    Erase = 0x4,
    Validate = 0x8,
    NoInternalPaint = 0x10,
    NoErase = 0x20,
    NoChildren = 0x40,
    AllChildren = 0x80,
    UpdateNow = 0x100,
    EraseNow = 0x200,
    Frame = 0x400,
    NoFrame = 0x800
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool RedrawWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lprcUpdate, IntPtr hrgnUpdate, RedrawWindowFlags flags);

[Flags]
private enum SetWindowPosFlags : uint
{
    SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000,
    SWP_DEFERERASE = 0x2000,
    SWP_DRAWFRAME = 0x0020,
    SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020,
    SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080,
    SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010,
    SWP_NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100,
    SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002,
    SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200,
    SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x0008,
    SWP_NOREPOSITION = 0x0200,
    SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400,
    SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001,
    SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004,
    SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040,
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags);

private const int WM_PAINT = 0x000F;
private const int WM_SIZE = 0x0005;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern Int64 SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Comment: [What is the difference between Minimize All and Show Desktop?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040527-00/?p=39153) explains what *Show Desktop* does. If you wish to mimic that you'd have to minimize and restore the window. Repositioning the window along the Z-axis is probably not required.

Comment: What makes you think the game will resize with the window? It's very well possible it's hardcoded for the resolution. Some of these programs were configurable, but only with a fixed list of resolution. Even today, not all games (far from this in fact) can run at arbitrary size

Comment: @SimonMourier The resolution _is_ hardcoded, but the output can be scaled to fit the new window size. This is what happens when show desktop happens (with a subsequent switch back to the game window of course).

Comment: Is the game a full screen exclusive DirectX window? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/demystifying-full-screen-optimizations/

Comment: @SimonMourier It is not, though it does support this mode via a settings switch.

Comment: Have you tried to minimize and restore the window ? If it works, it may be how the game is coded. Also can you try the Inspect tool from Windows SDK (inspect.exe) and use Action/Refresh menu from it on your game window.

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried Action/Refresh in inspect.exe (found it haha) and no it did not fix the problem. And yes, minimizing then restoring does work.

Comment: "*I have tried RedrawWindow*" With `RDW_INVALIDATE`, and perhaps `RDW_ERASE`,too?

Comment: Perhaps you could try sending `WM_SIZE` with the `SIZE_RESTORED` value? Did you pass the repaint value when calling `MoveWindow`? Perhaps you can show the actual code with what you have tried?

Comment: Is it useful to you to use `SetWindowPos` and specify `SWP_FRAMECHANGED`? This will send a [`WM_NCCALCSIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccalcsize) message. BTW, Could you please show some screenshots and code of this issue?

Comment: Is this game available somehow?

Comment: @SimonMourier Sure, though it's in Mandarin not English. [link](http://www.stoneage.com.tw/download.php?c=2). It needs a login to actually play but for the problem described here the login screen would suffice. Might need to select XP SP3 compatibility for it to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Spy++ to monitor the message of this game window, and found that it seems to redraw window content by processing `WM_MOVE`. Simply calling `PostMessage(hwnd,WM_MOVE,0,0)` could make the window updated(**NOTE THAT**: This solution is only useful for this game window.)

The general method is that you can use Spy++ to monitor window messages and compare the differences between the received messages when the behavior is different.

Another method is to add sizing border style to the window:

```
LONG_PTR stlyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
LONG_PTR ret = SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, stlyle | WS_SIZEBOX);
```

Then you can manually drag the border to change the size, of course you still need to manually move the window to update content.

Comment: Amazing! I never even thought adding sizable borders was possible :D

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there's a client window within your game's main window that does not change its size when the game's main window does. After all, it is not designed for resizing at all. You can evaluate the window hierachrchy of your application using [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-start-spy-increment?view=vs-2019), which ships with Visual studio, or a similar tool.
if there is a child window within the main window, you can try to send similar messages to it to make it resize.

Comment: Although this is a possibility, I have said in the question that spy++ does not show any child windows. This may not be conclusive, however, but I don't know any other tool that can do better than spy++.

Comment: If there were a child window Spy++ would reliably report it.